# Arel, Joins and Rails Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, join, arel

I've been stuck on a problem recently for a little while and found my way to Arel which looks like it should allow me to do OR's in my queries.

As a starting point I needed to convert an existing Rails 3 query to Arel and that's where I've run into problems.

The following scope and query works as I would expect it to.  It gives me the requests associated with a particular user's ads.

```
#in the Request class
scope :responder, lambda { |user| joins(:ad).where(:ads => { :user_id => user }) }

Request.responder(303).to_sql

=> "SELECT \"requests\".* FROM \"requests\" INNER JOIN \"ads\" ON \"ads\".\"id\" = \"requests\".\"ad_id\" WHERE (\"ads\".\"user_id\" = 303)"
```

According to doco on the Arel github page and Railscast 215 I should be able to do something like the following to replicate the query with Arel

```
  requests = Request.arel_table
  ads = Ad.arel_table
  where(requests.join(ads).on(ads[:id].eq(requests[:ad_id])))
```

This results in an error

```
TypeError: Cannot visit Arel::SelectManager
```

I can do the following in the console though

```
r = Request.arel_table
a = Ad.arel_table

r.join(a).to_sql
 => "SELECT  FROM \"requests\" INNER JOIN \"ads\" "
```

So it looks like it's forming the SQL request, however when you put that in a where

```
Request.where(r.join(a)).to_sql
```

I get the following

```
TypeError: Cannot visit Arel::SelectManager....
```

I've tried doing other Arel actions within the where and it works (e.g.)

```
Request.where(r[:status].eq(nil)).to_sql
 => "SELECT \"requests\".* FROM \"requests\" WHERE (\"requests\".\"status\" IS NULL)"
```

This is a little beyond my growing rails/ruby knowledge. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do OR's in rails 3, check out MetaWhere.  There's a nice railscast on it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch

Comment: Thanks DGM.  I have seen MetaWhere but I was trying to avoid adding another gem when it seems there's facilities already in rails.  I should take another look though.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `join_sources.first` on `Arel::SelectManager` and the pass this to joins

```
requests = Request.arel_table
ads = Ad.arel_table
Request.joins(requests.join(ads).on(ads[:id].eq(requests[:ad_id])).join_sources.first)
```

Comment: You can also just do `join_sources` joins will figure it out. I believe that would also pass all of them if your had multiple but don't quote me on the second part

Answer (score 8):

The larger answer here, is that despite the fancy, inspiring example here:
  http://magicscalingsprinkles.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/why-i-wrote-arel/

...Active Record doesn't actually support full Arel functionality. At least, not through relations or scopes. You can create any (most) queries in Arel, but in the end you're going to be using:

```
sql = User.arel_table.(something awesome in Arel).to_sql
users = User.find_by_sql(sql)
```

Technically, there's still a ".to_a" method, but it doesn't return ActiveRecord model instances, *and* it's deprecated.

{UPDATE}

http://erniemiller.org/projects/squeel/ is the best thing to happen to ActiveRecord, ever. All that Arel stuff, realized.

Comment: Your wordpress link is dead

Comment: I know! But it was a really good link back in early 2011. I'm sad that he's not showing off that project anymore.

Comment: archive.org link to zombie blog:  http://web.archive.org/web/20110202025045/http://magicscalingsprinkles.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/why-i-wrote-arel/

Answer (score 2):

I'm no Arel expert, but I think you want to combine the join and where scopes instead of including one within the other. So instead of

```
where(requests.join(ads).on(ads[:id].eq(requests[:ad_id])))
```

try (for instance):

```
requests.join(ads).on(ads[:id].eq(requests[:ad_id])).where(requests[:status].eq(nil))
```

Comment: Thanks zetetic.  I'll give that a go instead.

Comment: That works, if you add a ".to_sql" to the end and drop it inside of 
`Request.find_by_sql(...)`

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible solution I have found so far is something like the following:

```
class Request
  class << self
    def your_join_scope
      joins('INNER JOIN "ads" ON "ads"."id" = "requests"."ad_id"')
    end
  end
end
```

The power of it is that you can mix and match it with your other scopes

Comment: No need to use Arel::SqlLiteral
Why not just joins('INNER JOIN "ads" ON "ads"."id" = "requests"."ad_id"')