# Querying relations in ARel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I'm doing something like this:

```
@invoices = Invoice.order(:due_date)
@invoices = @invoices.where(:invoiced => true)
```

Now, I want to filter the invoices by the id of a related model (I need only the invoices where the id of the invoice's project's owner matches a certain id). At the moment I'm doing this:

```
owner_id = #get owner_id somehow
@invoices = @invoices.find_all do |invoice|
  invoice.project.owner_id == owner_id
end
```

Of course, this is a bit messy, and I'm doing it in the controller, which I'd rather not do. Also, it breaks down the whole point of ARel. I can't work out how to do the above using an ARel `where` clause though. Any ideas?

I can't just put this all into a class method, because the `order` and `where` are used for other code paths, and I'd have to duplicate them for this special case (which ain't right).

**Edit:** Looking at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072709/arel-joins-and-rails-queries) it looks like I may need to use [MetaWhere](http://railscasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch) to do this cleanly. Thoughts?

**Edit2:** I went with [fl00r's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802491/querying-relations-in-arel/5802697#5802697), adding a scope to Invoice:

```
#invoice.rb
scope :academic, lambda {
  academic_id = #get academic_id somehow
  joins(:project).where(:projects => { :owner_id => academic_id })
}
```

I also added scopes for `invoiced` and `not_invoiced`, so I can now do `@invoices.invoiced.academic` in my controller, which is much cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@invoices = Invoice.order(:due_date).joins(:project).
  where(:invoiced => true, :projects => {:owner_id => owner_id})
# you can also uniq the list
@invoices.uniq!
```

**UPD**

Also you can go another way

```
@owner = Owner.find_some
@invoices = @owner.projects.include(:invoices).map(&:invoices).flatten
```

Or even refactor a little:

```
class Owner < AR::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :invoices, :through => :projects
end

@invoices = @owner.invoices
```